# lattice plot error: need finite xlim values calls

Tags: r, data-science

Whenever I try and plot across factors I keep getting the error.

Here is how my data looks like:

```
str(dataWithNoNa)

## 'data.frame':    17568 obs. of  4 variables:
##  $ steps   : num  1.717 0.3396 0.1321 0.1509 0.0755 ...
##  $ date    : Factor w/ 61 levels "2012-10-01","2012-10-02",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ interval: int  0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 ...
##  $ dayType : Factor w/ 2 levels "Weekday","Weekend": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I am trying to plot using the lattice plotting system using Weekday/Weekend as a factor.

Here is what I tried:

```
plot(dataWithNoNa$steps~ dataWithNoNa$interval | dataWithNoNa$dayType, type="l")

Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
```

I even checked to make sure my data had no NAs:

```
sum(is.na(dataWithNoNa$interval))
## [1] 0
sum(is.na(dataWithNoNa$steps))
## [1] 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please use dput(), not str(), to output the structure so that the data can be used for a reproducible example.

Comment: Your plot formula looks like syntax for the `lattice`  package.

Comment: Isn't the `lattice` plot function named `xyplot`? It seems you are using base graphics with an illegal formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(lattice)

xyplot(steps ~ interval | factor(dayType), data=df)
```

Output:

[image]

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  steps=c(1.717,0.3396,0.1321,0.1509,0.0755),
  interval=c(0,5,10,15,20),
  dayType=c(1,1,1,2,2)
)
```

Comment: That worked. I needed to load the library - how embarassing. Thanks

Comment: It happens, no problem. Please mark this answer as a solution though to make it easier for people to answer in the future.